# Create dynamic angular table with generic typing for input data

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics, angular-components, tsconfig

I am creating a simple dynamic table component in Angular and I am trying to avoid using the any data type for the table data passed into it. When I add a generic T type I get an error in the html template.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ngtsc(7053)
dynamic-table.component.ts(7, 7): Error occurs in the template of component DynamicTableComponent.
```

dynamic-table.component.ts File

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TableHeader } from '../../models/dynamic-table.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-table',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-table.component.html',
})
export class DynamicTableComponent<T> {
  @Input() columns: TableHeader[] = [];
  @Input() data: T[] | null = [];
}
```

dynamic-table.component.html file

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of columns" scope="col">{{column.label}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{item[column.column]}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="data && data.length <= 0">
            <td [attr.colspan]="columns.length">* No valid treatments results were found.</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

dynamic-table.model.ts

```
export interface TableHeader {
  column: string;
  label: string;
}
```

I have tried updating the *ngFor in the template with `as typeof` and also with `as keyof` but that just seems to take it all worse. Removing the generic in the .ts file and changing the   `@Input() data: T[]` to  `@Input() data: any[]` works which is not whay I want though.

As discused in the comments setting the `"strict": false` in the tsconfig.json file resolves the issue. The setting `"strict": true` actual sets the following to true

```
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
```

The setting that is causing all the issues though is `"noImplicitAny": true` setting it to false though has the issue of not giving errors if you don't type variables or argument in functions  in your .ts files. This actually creates more issues in the future.

Does anyone else have an  idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: How do you call the selector `app-dynamic-table` in the Html of the ParentComponent?

Comment: I add is as part of the parent template ```<app-dynamic-table [columns]="columns" [data]="data$ | async"></app-dynamic-table>```

Comment: I think that the error can be in another place, take a look a [stackblitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wlvdd5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I think it has to do with the settings in `tsconfig.json`.  Locally I got the same error like Kumbirai Benjamin Deve, but then I copied the tsconfig-settings from Eliseo's stackblitz-example and it suddenly worked...

Comment: @Kumbirai Benjamin Deve: If in `tsconfig.json` you change the property `"strict"` to `false`, your solution might work.

Comment: yes thanks guys, that seemed to work. I will need to read up on the options in the tsconfig file just to be sure what setting ```"strict": false``` also affects

Comment: @kellermat setting the ```"strict": true``` sets the following to true as well in the tsconfig.json

```"useUnknownInCatchVariables": true, "noImplicitAny": true, "strictNullChecks": true,"strictFunctionTypes": true,"strictBindCallApply": true,"strictPropertyInitialization": true,"noImplicitThis": true,"alwaysStrict": true,```

The setting that is causing all the issues though is ```"noImplicitAny": true``` setting it to false though has the issue of not giving errors if you don't type variables and arguments in you .ts files. 

This actually creates more issues in the future.

Comment: I agree with you that changing the settings will have side-effects. Yet I fear there might be no satisfying solution that uses generics?
Maybe you could open a new SO-question where you approach the problem from a different perspective: You could describe your use-case and ask what would be the best way to tackle the problem in Angular. Maybe you would find out that using generics isn't really the way to go anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a component named `ConsumerComponent` where you are going to use this `app-dynamic-table`.

For the `consumer.component.html`:

```
<app-dynamic-table [columns]="columnSource" [data]="dataSource"></app-dynamic-table>
```

Now in the `consumer.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-consumer',
  templateUrl: './consumer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./consumer.component.scss']
})

export class ProductsComponent {
  columnSource: TableHeader[];
  dataSource: IProductModel[];

  constructor(){
    this.columnSource = [ // array of TableHeader type objects ];
    this.dataSource = [ // array of IProductModel type objects ];
  }
  // ...
}
```

Here `IProductModel` is the model for objects from the server. In my case, it looked like this:

```
export declare interface IProductModel{
    /**
     * Product Id
     * @type {Number}
     */
    id: number;
    /**
     * Product Category or Subcategory Id
     * @type {Number}
     */
    categoryId: number;
    /**
     * Product Category or Subcategory Name
     * @type {string}
     */
    category: string;
    /**
     * Product subcategory or Subcategory Id
     * @type {Number}
     */
    subcategoryId: number;
    /**
     * Product subcategory or Subcategory Name
     * @type {string}
     */
    subcategory: string;
    /**
     * Product Name
     * @type {string}
     */
    productName: string;
    /**
     * Product purchase price
     * @type {Number}
     */
    price: number;
    /**
     * Product retail price
     * @type {Number}
     */
    retailPrice: number;
}
```